# Delete tomcat6 from services

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I just uninstalled tomcat6 and installed tomcat7, and now that I want to start, stop or restart the service, ubuntu shows the two of them, for example

```
sudo service tomcat
```

And then ubuntu shows two alternatives, for both tomcat6 and tomcat7, but I don't have and I don't want tomcat6 to appear there, What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just clean the tomcat6 referred lines in `/etc/init.d/tomcat` could solve your question.

after clean  the file may like that:

```
TOMCATPATH=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27

case $1 in

start)
 echo “starting tomcat7 from $TOMCATPATH”
 sh $TOMCATPATH/bin/startup.sh
;;

stop)
 echo “stopping tomcat7 from $TOMCATPATH”
 sh $TOMCATPATH/bin/shutdown.sh
;;

restart)
 $0 stop
 $0 start
;;

*)
 echo $”usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}”
;;
esac

exsit 0
```

---

suggestion to uninstall a software:

```
sudo apt-get purge xxxx-software
```

`purge` will also removes config files.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @eLRuLL how did you uninstall tomcat6 and what's the content of `/etc/init.d/tomcat`

Comment: uninstall with apt-get remove tomcat6, and I have tomcat6 and tomcat7 on /etc/init.d/, about the content, they are both similar.

Comment: @eLRuLL updated answer, hope it could help u.

Comment: but there is no `/etc/init.d/tomcat` file there are both tomcat6 and tomcat7 files.

Comment: @eLRuLL remove tomcat6